# Python regex: substitute all occurrence of a certain string NOT after a specific character

Tags: python, regex

How can I substitute all occurrence of a certain string NOT after a specific character in Python?

For example, I want to substitute all occurrence of `abc` NOT with a `x` before them with `def`. Here is the code:

```
re.sub(r'(^|[^x])abc', r'\1def', string)
```

If the string doesn't have consecutive `abc`s, the code works perfectly. However, if I have `string='abcabc'`, the code won't work. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

With a negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion `(?<!...)` *(i.e. not preceded by)*:

```
(?<!x)abc
```

In a replacement:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!x)abc', r'def', string)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
result = re.sub("(?<!x)abc", "def", subject)
```

- The negative lookbehind `(?<!x)` asserts that what precedes is not `x`
- `abc` matches `abc`
- We replace with `def`

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)